# How does Tomcat handle multiple SSL certs in the keystore?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https, keystore

We have an architecture where several Java 7 Tomcat apps communicate with a special web service (also a Tomcat app living on a different VM) over HTTPS.

Newer SHA-2 based SSL certs are not natively trusted by many Java 7 JREs. So one solution is to upgrade the Java 7 client apps to Java 8, whose distributions all support SHA-2. However, for reasons outside the scope of this question, 2 of our apps are massive and cannot be upgraded to Java 8 any time soon.

I am hoping that I could put 2 SSL certs inside the web service's keystore, and so we would have an old Java 7 friendly SHA-1 cert as well as the newer SHA-2 cert. Hopefully client apps could "choose" which cert to use, and hence, Java 7 apps would trust the old one, and Java 8 apps might trust either.

So I ask: how does Tomcat 8 behave when the keystore has multiple SSL certs inside of it? Does it just serve back the first cert, or does it present the HTTPS client with all available certs and allow them to choose which one to use? Or does something completely different happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'am not aware of any server running on multiple certificates on one port. But what you can do is to define another connector listening on port 8434 in your server.xml configuration pointing to the newer certificate tech. You can use the same keystore but you have to add the parameter `keyAlias` in your connector configuration to define the proper alias to use.